# How to map custom domain to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk URL?

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cname

I'm following the instructions [Using Custom Domains with AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) to map a custom domain to an [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) URL.

My Elastic Beanstalk URL is as follows:

```
http://myenvironment-specific-string.elasticbeanstalk.com/
```

I've created a CNAME record that says:

```
www.example.com     myenvironment-specific-string.elasticbeanstalk.com  8 hrs
```

I've also looked up the CNAME using MxToolBox' [CNAME Lookup tool](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/CNAMELookup.aspx) where it shows it correctly.
But when I try `www.example.com`, it doesn't show up.

Am I missing something? I'm stuck and this is racking my brains apart! Help me! :(

Comment: When did you create the CNAME record? DNS updates take a while to propagate through the internet.

Comment: You're right. It's working now. When I wrote this question it was 1 hour already.Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 11):

1. Use Route53
2. Create a record set with these values:

   Name: www.example.com

   Type: A - IPv4 address

   Alias: Yes

   Alias Target: [click and choose your elastic load balancer]

   Alias Hosted Zone ID: [auto fills in when you choose the above, you can match this to your logs]

Without using Route53, you may be fighting an uphill battle, I'm not sure.

Comment: Hey @kross I did it with CNAME as mentioned in the EBS doc. It works. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Hi @kross! I just did what you posted, and for some reason is not making any changes on my domain. I am wondering if it's a matter of time to make the changes or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @pompeyo if you had the domain previously listed in your Route53 record set, then you may have to wait for DNS propagation.  If not, it should be established immediately.  Make sure you selected the right Alias Target.

Answer (score 0):

From GoDaddy (probably not best way) seem to work for me.

1. cname www MYENVIRONMENT.elasticbeanstalk.com
2. Forwarding feature: forward to: [www.MYDOMAIN.com](http://www.MYDOMAIN.com) (Type: Permanent: 301, Settings: Forward only)

I guess the way it work MYDOMAIN.com forwards to 1) www then www goes to MYENVIRONMENT.elasticbeanstalk.com